# Accessing array values returned from SQL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, postgresql, type-conversion

I am certain this is very simple, but I'm a noob to Ruby and can't seem to find the answer to a very basic question.

I have a table with a list of words in PostgreSQL.  I am getting a return value from a query to get a count of rows.  When I try to assign this returned value to a variable "wordcount," I can't seem to get just the integer value.  For example, if I try to use wordcount (as obtained below), Ruby throws an error "can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)."  In short, how do I convert the value obtained from the query to an integer?  Thanks in advance.

```
q = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words'
res  = conn.exec(q)
wordcount = res.values[0]
puts wordcount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PostgreSQL (and probably most other connectors), it would be:

```
wordcount = res[0]["count"]
```

are you sure you don't want to just do:

```
Word.count
```

though?

Comment: Yep good spot - though I actually meant res[0]["count"]. And yep that's true, but thought it might be worth a mention given the OP's self-professed noobishness!

Answer (score 1):

The [`exec`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.11.0/PGconn#exec-instance_method) method returns a `PGResult` instance and [`PGResult#values`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.11.0/PGresult#values-instance_method):

> Returns all tuples as an array of arrays.

So your `res` is an array of arrays: one entry for each row in the result set and each entry will itself be an array with one entry per column. They're strings as well, try this:

```
wordcount = res.getvalue(0, 0).to_i
puts wordcount
```

Answer (score 0):

The database library is giving you a return value that supports the return of multiple rows. You are probably getting an array with a single row that contains an array with a single column that takes your value.